# Issue with handling DST in momentjs

Tags: time, momentjs, dst

I've got a question about handling DST in momentjs.

Let's assume that I'm currently in GMT+1 timezone and observe standard (winter) time, so my UTC offset is +01:00. If I execute:
`moment('2018-02-26T10:12:00+01:00').format('LLL')` I will get `"26 February 2018 10:12"` as I would expect.

However, if I execute `moment('2018-04-26T10:12:00+01:00').format('LLL')` (so with a date which is inside DST period) I will get `"26 April 2018 11:12"` so it looks like momentjs didn't take into account a DST switch which will take place between now and that date.

Is this actually an expected behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed expected behavior and Moment is working correctly.

You have specified an offset in your input time of `+01:00`, but the offset in effect in your local time zone at that time is actually `+02:00` (assuming most European places in CET/CEST).  Therefore, the instant you describe is an hour off, and thus your results are an hour off.

If you omit the offset from your input, you'll see that Moment behaves as you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

```
moment(date).add(moment().utcOffset(), 'm').format('DD-MM-YYYY - h:mm:ss');
```

This works perfectly fine for me. It converts utc time to local time by adding/subtracting utc offset time while catering to DST